# How to retrieve other user controls information from user control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Index.aspx, which is using one user control,"SocialElement"several times(with different names).

I want to detect from this user control "SocialElement" about: how many this user control already exists/loads in Index page.

The following is my code:

Index.aspx

```
  <MyUserControl:SocialElement ID="Element" runat="server"/>

  <MyUserControl:SocialElement ID="Element1" runat="server"/>  

  <MyUserControl:SocialElement ID="Element2" runat="server"/>
```

SocialElement.ascx's code behind

```
 protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var listSocialShare = Page.Controls.OfType<SocialElement>();
   int number = listSocialShare.Count();
}
```

However, I saw the value of "number" is always ZERO when each time the SocialElement.ascx is being loaded by Index.aspx.

Do I really get SocialElement.ascx's total quantity from "Page.Controls.OfType()"?

If not, how to?Thank you.

Comment: `Page.Controls` is only for controls that are direct children of `Page`. You need a recursive algorithm to iterate over the children's children etc.

Comment: Hi @mason, in my website, I only allow Index.aspx use SocialElement.ascx, and others can not.

Comment: That doesn't change what I said in my comment. Controls are in a hierachy, and the `.Controls` property only returns that control's children, so you need to write an algorithm to recurse over them and search all levels of the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mason is right about needing to *recursively* look for the control. You need a method to loop through *all* of the controls:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var listSocialShare = FindControlsRecursive<SocialElement>(Page);
    int number = listSocialShare.Count();
}

private IEnumerable<T> FindControlsRecursive<T>(Control root)
{
    foreach (Control child in root.Controls)
    {
        if (child is T)
        {
            yield return (T)Convert.ChangeType(child, typeof(T));
        }

        if (child.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (T c in FindControlsRecursive<T>(child))
            {
                yield return c;
            }
        }
    }
}
```